# How to access specific email from EWS exchange server

Tags: c#, office365, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am trying to get a specific email from from EWS using C# but could not find a way to identify a specific email.

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1);
            service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(myemail, password);
            service.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            service.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
            ItemView itemsView = new ItemView(5);
            string querystring = "Kind:email";                

            FindItemsResults<Item> itemResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, querystring, view: itemsView);
```

The FindItems method gives emails based on query string. I save `EmailMessage.InternetMessageId` and `EmailMessage.Id` and subject etc details in my database. In my case I may have emails with same subject and little different body content.

Later, based on user action I want to get specific email from exchange server. Is there any method I can use and get email based on `EmailMessage.InternetMessageId` or `EmailMessage.Id` ? Are these Ids reliable? I could not find a method in docs. Currently I am thinking of read emails based on subject and then filter the results based on `EmailMessage.Id.UniqueId`

Is there any good alternate way to get specific email from exchange server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IntenetMessageId should be unique but there is no guarantee that it will be because of the number of different processes that can set the Id's.

If you want to get a specific message based on its InternetMessageId then you need to use the Extended property rather then the strongly typed one eg

```
  String MessageID = "<blah@1223434556com">"
  ItemView ivew = new ItemView(3);
  service.TraceEnabled = true;
  ExtendedPropertyDefinition PidTagInternetMessageId = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(4149, MapiPropertyType.String);
  SearchFilter sf = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(PidTagInternetMessageId, MessageID);
  FindItemsResults<Item> iCol = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, sf, ivew);

  foreach (Item item in iCol.Items)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(item.Subject);
  }
```

You can export the message to a EML file using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-export-items-by-using-ews-in-exchange

Comment: Thank you. What is 4149 value represent in ExtendedPropertyDefinition? Could not find details in docs.

Comment: If message id is not reliable is it ok to use EmailMessage.Id.UniqueId? Based on this doc I thought unique id more reliable https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/ews-identifiers-in-exchange

Comment: Its depends on what your trying to do for most things the InternetMessageId will work fine. The problem with using the uniqueId is if the message is moved between folders this will change. Otherwise look at something like the pidtagsearchkey property https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/pidtagsearchkey-canonical-property